# Very slow select SQL queries inside Virtual Machine

Tags: mysql, docker, performance, mariadb, virtual-machine

We have developed a backend application that uses a MariaDB Server. For deployment, the backend runs in a Docker container and the MariaDB server runs in another Docker container (using the official image). We set up a Docker Compose project and everything works fine.

However, if we deploy the application in a Virtual Machine (based on Kubuntu or Lubuntu) using the Docker containers, some select SQL queries take forever when they take less than a second to run on the host machine.

The host machine has SSD storage, 8 cores and 32GB or RAM. The VM is created with 4 cores and 20GB of RAM. It seems that using more cores or RAM on the VM does not make any difference and we wonder what can be the cause of this really low performance. Any ideas are appreciated as we have try many things without success.

The query:

```
select  distinct gene1_.id as id1_6_, gene1_.defaultName as defaultN2_6_,
        gene1_.species as species3_6_
    from  gene_in_interactome geneininte0_
    inner join  gene gene1_  ON geneininte0_.gene=gene1_.id
    inner join  gene_name names2_  ON gene1_.id=names2_.geneId
    inner join  gene_name_value names3_  ON names2_.geneId=names3_.geneId
      and  names2_.source=names3_.geneSource
    where  (geneininte0_.interactome in (666))
      and  (cast(gene1_.id as char) like 'arg%'
              or  names3_.name like 'arg%'
           )
    order by  gene1_.id asc
    limit  10
```

I have already identified that the critical part is `(cast(gene1_.id as char) like 'arg%' or names3_.name like 'arg%')` due to the `names3_` that requires the last inner join.

And here are the create tables:

```
gene_in_interactome | CREATE TABLE `gene_in_interactome` (
  `gene` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `interactome` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `species` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gene`,`interactome`,`species`),
  KEY `FKsswgs3cc7avkugqvq78sv21xg` (`interactome`),
  KEY `FKtpcnom6fs9jal4qfgao444cse` (`species`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKa02a13n65pbhq1m1ehk63f4es` FOREIGN KEY (`gene`) REFERENCES `gene` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKsswgs3cc7avkugqvq78sv21xg` FOREIGN KEY (`interactome`) REFERENCES `interactome` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKtpcnom6fs9jal4qfgao444cse` FOREIGN KEY (`species`) REFERENCES `species` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 |

| gene  | CREATE TABLE `gene` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `defaultName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `species` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDXnkshoslla6kq08gqh38grefke` (`id`,`species`),
  KEY `FKg5uaph3wq3eu765ch9lkq6qi1` (`species`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKg5uaph3wq3eu765ch9lkq6qi1` FOREIGN KEY (`species`) REFERENCES `species` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 |

| gene_name | CREATE TABLE `gene_name` (
  `geneId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`geneId`,`source`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKltnrhrbud9fvdilc74lybdvio` FOREIGN KEY (`geneId`) REFERENCES `gene` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 |

| gene_name_value | CREATE TABLE `gene_name_value` (
  `geneId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `geneSource` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `FK_gene_name_gene_name_values` (`geneId`,`geneSource`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_gene_name_gene_name_values` FOREIGN KEY (`geneId`, `geneSource`) REFERENCES `gene_name` (`geneId`, `source`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 |
```

Comment: My car is driving slow, but it's driving on a [8 lane highway](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/8+lane+highway)   Or, in other words, what info is missing?

Comment: More specifically, show us the queries, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. I have edited the post with this information.

Answer (score 0):

```
    cast(gene1_.id as char) like 'arg%'
              or  names3_.name like 'arg%'
```

Is "arg" a value coming from the user?  Beware of SQL Injection.

Both the `OR` and `CAST` may significantly hurt performance.  Programmatically generate the query by checking whether "arg" is numeric; if it is, use

```
WHERE id = 'arg'
```

if not, use

```
WHERE name LIKE 'arg%'
```

Meanwhile, some of these indexes may help:

```
geneininte0_:  INDEX(interactome, gene)
names3_:  INDEX(name, geneId,  geneSource)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.  That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

Does the table `gene_name` have more than the 2 columns?  If not, why does it exist??

```
KEY(id, species)
```

Since `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, which is "clustered" with the data, this index is essentially useless.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rick!

Regarding your questions:
1) Yes, it is an user argument, we will be aware of SQL injection.
2) The argument is not numeric, it is a text that we want and we want to found words (names) starting with the letters in "arg".
3) Table `gene_name` only have two columns. It exist because for each row in table `gene` we want to store several names, which are in this `gene_name` table.

Comment: Another point is what I said in mi first message: the query runs very quickly (we do not need to optimize it) on our production servers but it takes forever on a Virtual Machine .... my guess is that the environment of the Virtual Machine may has something that harms performance but do not know why. I thought it could by disk speed but did some tests and performed almost like in the host.

Comment: @hlfernandez - What are the differences in the `my.cnf` config files for the two instances?

Comment: They are exactly the same because we use the same Docker image with the same configuration.

Comment: Are you saying that you have two 20GB VMs and the machine is 32GB total?

Comment: My laptop has 32GB of RAM and 8 cores. Then, I have one two VMs with 20GB and 4 cores (one with Lubuntu and one with Kubuntu).

Comment: @hlfernandez - Have you given 20GB to _each_ VM?

Comment: Yes Rick, but I only run once at time.

Comment: 20GB -- OK.  Back to `arg`...  You say "The argument is not numeric".  If that is a fact, then you don't need `cast(gene1_.id as char) like 'arg%'`, do you?

Comment: I think i did not explained it well: arg can be numeric or text. If arg is numeric, we want it to be compared against `gene1_.id` (which is numeric), and if it is text, we want it to be compared against `names3_.name`. Queries are created by JPA. I remember testing the query with only one part of the `or`, and the part that runs very slow is `names3_.name like 'arg%'`.

Comment: @hlfernandez - Have the application determine numeric vs text; then issue one query against id (with `=`) versus another against the varchar (with `LIKE`).  That eliminates a major performance issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments Rick! I will repeat the queries separately as soon as possible to compare the performance times and see if it is worth doing that in the application, as in our production server works properly (but we are very interested in having it working on the VM for personal use).